Jetty Server 9 to 12 migration
I had a class: MockServerHandler I use in my itests using Jetty 9 which I had to migrate to Jetty 12.
Before the migration (Jetty 9):
public class MockServerHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            log.debug("Got request for: {} request type {} ", target, request.getMethod());
            handleDownload(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Mock handler caught and exception", e);
        }
    }

    private void handleDownload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        byte[] byteBuffer = getContentToReturn();
        long lastModified = getLastModified();
        String contentType = getContentType();
        int returnCode = getReturnCode();

        response.setStatus(returnCode);
        if (lastModified > 0L) {
            response.setDateHeader(HttpHeader.LAST_MODIFIED.asString(), lastModified);
        }
        response.setContentType(contentType);        
        response.setContentLength(byteBuffer.length);

        OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.length);
        response.flushBuffer();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}

After bumping to Jetty 12:
public class MockServerHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    @Override
    public boolean handle(Request request, Response response, Callback callback)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            String target = request.getHttpURI().getPath();
            log.debug("Got request for: {} request type {} ", target, request.getMethod());
            handleDownload(request, response);
            callback.succeeded();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            callback.failed(e);
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            log.error("Mock handler caught and exception", e);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void handleDownload(Request request, Response response) {
        byte[] byteBuffer = getContentToReturn();
        long lastModified = getLastModified();
        String contentType = getContentType();
        int returnCode = getReturnCode();

        response.setStatus(returnCode);
        if (lastModified > 0L) {
            response.getHeaders().addDateField(HttpHeader.LAST_MODIFIED.asString(), lastModified);
        }
        response.getHeaders().add(HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType);
response.getHeaders().add(HttpHeader.CONTENT_LENGTH, byteBuffer.length);

        OutputStream outputStream = Content.Sink.asOutputStream(response);
        outputStream.write(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.length);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}

After these changes my integration tests started to fail. Some due to read timeout, others expect UTF-8 encoded response body and suddenly fail complaining the first byte isn't compliant, and more.
I'm clearly missing something, as I tried to make the least amount of changes possible to retain behavior.
I noticed DefaultHandler passes super(InvocationType.NON_BLOCKING); which I did not expect (it wasn't non-blocking on Jetty 9, right?). I tried extending Handler.Abstract directly but that didn't change anything.
Am I violating the new Jetty contract somehow? I've read the docs carefully but couldn't see anything I am doing blatantly wrong.
Any advice to understand how it works and what I'm missing is very much appreciated.

What is that DefaultHandler you extend from?

Thanks for your reply @JoakimErdfelt. This is it: https://javadoc.jetty.org/jetty-12/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/DefaultHandler.html

Why are you extending from that??  Even in Jetty 9 that would be a very strange decision.

Can't you just use a ResourceHandler properly configured instead of doing this yourself?

It's hard for me to answer that as I am not the original author. I just got the task to upgrade Jetty from 9 to 12. Why is it a very strange decision, if I may ask?

DefaultHandler in Jetty 9 is the "oh shit, nothing handled my request, I need to produce a response".  In Jetty 12 it is the same, but also handles requests for favicon.ico.

We are using this in our itests, so I guess the intention was full control rather than getting ResourceHandler's benefits. But that's just my guess. In regards to my code, do you see anything blatantly wrong that I'm doing?

If you have a complete byte[] array of your content, don't use a blocking OutputStream, just send it as is, there's no need to get overly complicated with the OutputStream class.
Your Jetty 12 implementation doesn't even handle content-length properly.
Separate your concerns.

Get the response data (fail
Prepare the response metadata (headers, status codes)
Write the response body content (and manage the Callback)

The minute you mix these you will have a messy set of code that becomes hard to maintain.
package handlers;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpHeader;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.Callback;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public abstract class MockDownloadHandler extends Handler.Abstract
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MockDownloadHandler.class);

    @Override
    public boolean handle(Request request, Response response, Callback callback) throws Exception
    {
        String target = Request.getPathInContext(request);
        LOG.debug("Got request for: {} request type {} ", target, request.getMethod());

        // Get response content
        ByteBuffer responseBody;

        try
        {
            responseBody = ByteBuffer.wrap(getContentToReturn());
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            callback.failed(e);
            return true; // you handled the failure.
        }

        // Prepare response metadata
        long lastModified = getLastModified();
        //   The contentType string here should have the `;charset=` section defined too.
        //   Example: "text/html;charset=utf-8" or "text/html;charset=iso8859-1"
        //   Note: not all content-types support a `;charset=` here, some are implied.
        //         for example json is implied to be `utf-8` but never reported in this
        //         content-type as `;charset=utf-8`, that would, in fact, be a violation
        //         of the json spec to include the `;charset=` entry.
        String contentType = getContentType();
        int returnCode = getReturnCode();

        response.setStatus(returnCode);
        response.getHeaders().add(HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType);
        // If you leave this out, you are subject to possible Transfer-Encoding: chunked responses.
        response.getHeaders().add(HttpHeader.CONTENT_LENGTH, responseBody.remaining());
        if (lastModified > 0)
            response.getHeaders().addDateField(HttpHeader.LAST_MODIFIED.asString(), lastModified);

        // Send the response
        response.write(true, responseBody, callback);
        return true;
    }

    protected abstract int getReturnCode();

    protected abstract String getContentType();

    protected abstract long getLastModified();

    public byte[] getContentToReturn()
    {
        // Be careful of proper conversion to bytes.
        // If the data is already binary, no need to do anything to encode it.
        // But if the data starts out as text, the conversion to bytes needs to be encoded
        // based on the same charset that you are going to report back on the `Content-Type`
        // response header.

        // Example: a string to byte conversion using UTF-8
        return "Hello € euro".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}

You probably want your getContentToReturn() step also be mime-type and charset aware, so that you can perform the correct behaviors to the content conversion to bytes, and also carry over the proper content-type (with charset) too.
Also be aware of MimeTypes object, it can do a few things for you.
Like let you know about assumed vs inferred charsets.
Example.
package mimetypes;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.eclipse.jetty.http.MimeTypes;

public class MimeTypeDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MimeTypes mimeTypes = new MimeTypes();

        dump(mimeTypes, "text/html");
        dump(mimeTypes, "text/html;charset=iso8859-1");
        dump(mimeTypes, "image/jpeg");
        dump(mimeTypes, "application/json");
        dump(mimeTypes, "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        dump(mimeTypes, "application/json;charset=us-ascii");
    }

    public static void dump(MimeTypes mimeTypes, String applicationSpecifiedContentType)
    {
        System.out.printf("%n-- dump: \"%s\" --%n", applicationSpecifiedContentType);
        System.out.printf("  mime-type = %s%n", MimeTypes.getContentTypeWithoutCharset(applicationSpecifiedContentType));
        System.out.printf("  charset (string) = %s%n", MimeTypes.getCharsetFromContentType(applicationSpecifiedContentType));
        System.out.printf("  charset (class) = %s%n", mimeTypes.getCharset(applicationSpecifiedContentType));
        System.out.printf("  assumed charset = %s%n", mimeTypes.getAssumedCharset(applicationSpecifiedContentType));
        System.out.printf("  inferred charset = %s%n", mimeTypes.getInferredCharset(applicationSpecifiedContentType));
        System.out.printf("  charset inferred from content-type = %s%n", mimeTypes.getCharsetInferredFromContentType(applicationSpecifiedContentType));
        String contentTypeHeaderValue = toHeaderValue(mimeTypes, applicationSpecifiedContentType);
        System.out.printf("  Content-Type (clean header to send) = %s%n", contentTypeHeaderValue);
    }

    private static String toHeaderValue(MimeTypes mimeTypes, String rawContentType)
    {
        // Get the mimetype from the raw content-type string
        String mimeType = MimeTypes.getContentTypeWithoutCharset(rawContentType);

        // Figure out the charset, normalized if found, add if missing and not assumed.
        String rawCharset = MimeTypes.getCharsetFromContentType(rawContentType);
        if (rawCharset == null)
        {
            Charset inferredCharset = mimeTypes.getInferredCharset(mimeType);
            if (inferredCharset != null)
                rawCharset = inferredCharset.name();
        }

        if (rawCharset != null)
            return String.format("%s;charset=%s", mimeType, rawCharset);
        else
            return mimeType;
    }
}

With output of ...
-- dump: "text/html" --
  mime-type = text/html
  charset (string) = null
  charset (class) = UTF-8
  assumed charset = null
  inferred charset = UTF-8
  charset inferred from content-type = UTF-8
  Content-Type (clean header to send) = text/html;charset=UTF-8

-- dump: "text/html;charset=iso8859-1" --
  mime-type = text/html
  charset (string) = iso8859-1
  charset (class) = ISO-8859-1
  assumed charset = null
  inferred charset = null
  charset inferred from content-type = null
  Content-Type (clean header to send) = text/html;charset=iso8859-1

-- dump: "image/jpeg" --
  mime-type = image/jpeg
  charset (string) = null
  charset (class) = null
  assumed charset = null
  inferred charset = null
  charset inferred from content-type = null
  Content-Type (clean header to send) = image/jpeg

-- dump: "application/json" --
  mime-type = application/json
  charset (string) = null
  charset (class) = UTF-8
  assumed charset = UTF-8
  inferred charset = null
  charset inferred from content-type = null
  Content-Type (clean header to send) = application/json

-- dump: "application/json;charset=UTF-8" --
  mime-type = application/json
  charset (string) = utf-8
  charset (class) = UTF-8
  assumed charset = null
  inferred charset = null
  charset inferred from content-type = null
  Content-Type (clean header to send) = application/json;charset=utf-8

-- dump: "application/json;charset=us-ascii" --
  mime-type = application/json
  charset (string) = us-ascii
  charset (class) = US-ASCII
  assumed charset = null
  inferred charset = null
  charset inferred from content-type = null
  Content-Type (clean header to send) = application/json;charset=us-ascii

This shows now the application provided Content-Type (with optional charset) can be interrogated and also resolved into a string that is appropriate to use on HTTP protocol for the Content-Type header value.

Thanks a lot! I will try this very soon. I noticed you didn't call callback.succeeded();. Is this intentional?

About the content length, it was my bad, I missed a line when constructing the question. Added it in edit now.
Also, the reason I am using OutputStream is because in the original code (I abbreviated it for the question), in some cases, we wrap the OutputStream with GZIPOutputStream, so I'm a bit stuck with it. I didn't ask about it specifically because investigating the itests that fail did not lead me to that code at all (we skip it 90% of the time).

OutputStream outputStream = Content.Sink.asOutputStream(response);                         if (isEnableGzip()) {                             response.getHeaders().add(HttpHeader.CONTENT_ENCODING, "gzip");                             outputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream);                         }
Unsure how to migrate this code without using Content.Sink.asOutputStream(response)

Use GzipHandler for that, don't use the GZIPOutputStream.

The callback.succeeded() (or failed()) is handled by response.write()

To do GZIP properly you need to pay attention to what the request says it can handle, along with extra topics like last-modified, etag, if-modified-since, etc...  All of that is handled by GzipHandler.  If you want it to be optional, then configure the includes/excludes to fit your use cases.
